# I can't realise what is wrong with this piece of code - Notification.requestPermission();

Tags: javascript, permissions, notifications

Take a look at the example JavaScript - Explain what issues implementing this onto your site may cause and explain how it could be prevented:

```js
(function() {
  Notification.requestPermission();
})();
```

---

I've the exercise above and I can't figure out what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a few issues that come from this code.

---

**1. Not checking if `Notification` is supported**

In some browsers, `Notification` isn't supported. Due to this, you have to check if it is in the `window`, otherwise it will throw an error.

To do this, you can use the following code.

```js
if (!("Notification" in window)) {
  console.log("Your browser doesn't support notifications.");
} else {
  Notification.requestPermission();
}
```

This will check if `Notification` isn't in the global `window` object (basically, checking if `window.Notification` is `undefined`).

---

**2. Not checking if `Notification` has already been granted**

Another thing that could be the issue is the fact that you aren't checking if `Notification` has already been granted. This can cause annoyance with the user.

To check if it has already been granted before asking the user for permission, you can add an `if`/`else` statement, like so.

```js
if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
  const notification = new Notification("Hello, world!");
} else {
  Notification.requestPermission();
}
```

This checks if the `permission` is `granted`, so that you can just send the notification without pestering the user with confirmation dialogs.

---

**3. Not using a `Promise`**

The function `Notification.requestPermission()` used to have a callback instead of a `Promise`. But, in favour of Promises, it is now deprecated.

According to [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/requestPermission#parameters) on the `callback` parameter:

> An optional callback function that is called with the permission value. **Deprecated in favor of the promise return value.**

Due to this, you need to use a `Promise` with the function.

**Important: Safari doesn't yet support the `Promise` method. You need to use callbacks instead.**

To do this, you can simply use the code below.

```js
Notification
  .requestPermission()
  .then((permission) => {
    if (permission === "granted") {
      const notify = new Notification("Hello, world!");
    }
  });
```

Basically, this code will run the `.then()` method when the user has accepted/denied the notification access.

There are three possible values for the `permission` parameter in the `.then()` method.

| Value | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `granted` | The user has granted permission for notifications. |
| `denied` | The user has denied permission for notifications. |
| `default` | Default option. |

If the user has granted permission, we send them a notification using the `Notification` class.

---

In conclusion, there are three issues that I have spotted in this code.

1. Not checking if `Notification` is supported
2. Not checking if `Notification` has already been granted
3. Not using a `Promise`

All of the code extracted from these solutions result in this code below. You can use this code, which will rid all of the issues.

```js
(function () {
  // 1. Not checking if Notification is supported
  if (!("Notification" in window)) {
    console.log("Your browser doesn't support notifications.");
  }

  // 2. Not checking if Notification has already been granted
  else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
    const notification = new Notification("Hello, world!");
  }
  
  // 3. Not using a Promise
  else {
    Notification
      .requestPermission()
      .then((permission) => {
        if (permission === "granted") {
          const notify = new Notification("Hello, world!");
        }
      });
   }
})();
```

These are the issues that I think could come from this code.

Comment: Safari doesn't support the Promise method.  You need to keep using the callbacks until that happens.

Comment: Yes, I forgot about that. I'll edit my answer about that.